# (JAVA) Проблемы с датами

Tags: дата, java

Есть пример, кот. я взял с www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/java/‎ (статья про работу с датами)

запускаю у себя следующий код (кот. должен вывести возраст)

```
Date birthDate = new Date (1986, 1, 19);
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTime(new Date()); 
int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
calendar.setTime(birthDate); 
int birthYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
System.out.println(currentYear - birthYear);
```

на выходе получаю -1873

Помогите разобраться, что не так? Как правильно вычислить возраст человека?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что надо `new Date (86, 1, 19);` и оно **Deprecated**. Т.е. надо использовать сразу календарь:

```
// calendar.setTime(birthDate); 
calendar.set(1986, 1, 19); //февраль, да?
```

Answer (score 1):

При создании экземпляра `birthDate` используйте значение 86 вместо 1986 (см. [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29)).

Кроме того, обратите внимание на то, что используемый вами конструктор класса `Date` обозначен как устаревший (deprecated) и не рекомендован к использованию.